# Rename full project Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, project

I have renamed a project following everything that I found by myself and here and it works but only a little.

It seems renamed, but when you check the app info in your device, or you deinstall it, the old name is still there.

How can I do a full rename?

Old name was WifiHome and I want to rename it to Wifi Sentinel.

build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.grenderg.wifisentinel"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.grenderg.wifisentinel" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/appName"
        android:theme="@style/WifiSentinel">
        <activity
            android:name="org.grenderg.wifisentinel.activities.BaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/appName"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="org.grenderg.wifisentinel.services.WifiScanService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**appName = Wifi Sentinel**

Renamed everywhere but not here on the info:

[image]

Comment: Project name doesn't show in the device, do you mean the app name? Or the app package?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the app name when you look the info or when you deinstall it. (Not as simply as replacing it on manifest)

Comment: check  android:label in manifest and change there as your requirement

Comment: Done and it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a bug in devices where te app has been installed before with the old name, I have tried to install on a device where I have never installed the app and the name is shown correctly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on your root project directory
2. Select Refactor -> Rename
3. Select rename project and change the name there.
4. Also Select rename module and change it there as well. If you get an message saying module name already changed thats fine.
5. Now right-click on the project root folder again and select Open Module Settings.
6. Under the Modules section remove whatever folders are associated to your old project name.
7. Apply Settings and hit OK. and Restart Android Studio.

Comment: http://s13.postimg.org/9v72dxp87/Screenshot_180415_12_45_05.png

Donde and not working.

Answer (score 0):

There's a build.gradle file inside your app folder. You have to change the applicationId in there, modify it from AndroidManifest file, as well. Then sync your project with gradle, clean it and rebuild it.

Comment: I have tried it and it's not working, check the question I have added some info.

Answer (score 0):

right after advised by other people  refactor renaming  and gradle file editing :

1. In Android Studio go to top bar:
   File => Settings => Build, Execution, Deployment => Build Tools => Gradle
2. Now here you have to uncheck "offline work".
3. Enable network on your comp.
4. Clean your project (Build => Clean Project)+Run it. 
   After you see it s all ok with renaming the app_name/label check again "offline work" 
   (Have made these on android studio 1.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, no errors but the installed apk had the old name, BUT when testing the game I noticed the old name on the action bar which gave me the clue to the answer,

go to your resources folder, then values folder, then open the strings.xml file. here you should see something like this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Rhg Timecard</string>
```

Change this (in my case it is Rhg Timecard) to your new name.
you should be all set now.

Answer (score 0):

In android Studio go to
res>values>string.xml and change the app there.

[image]

Comment: both serves same purpose here. so that why I chose image over code.

Comment: No, they don't. Actually, images are often blocked in companies. Plus, you cannot copy code from an image. You should always try to post text.